# Extracting ISO file using Java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, extract, iso

Is there any way to Extract content of ISO file (all directories and files inside) to a give directory in a local path? Specifically using Java in windows environment.

is there any library you may suggest? or is there any work around to do so ?

thanks.

Comment: You can use winrar command line to extract content of ISO file, but it is paid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend the following

**Java ISO Extraction**

- JAVA ISO tools 
  https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools
- Loopy
  http://loopy.sourceforge.net/
- JIIC: 
  [Java ISO Image Creator  (a bit old -- uses Java 1.4)](http://jiic.berlios.de/)

Comment: Is there any other alternative which is actively being maintained? Seems these libraries are not being maintained anymore.

Comment: JAVA ISO tools is a fork of JIIC

Answer (score 3):

By the time I am writing, libraries used in other answers are outdated. So I recommend [sevenzipjbinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Loopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loopy/).

> Loopy is a Java API for accessing various file systems in a read-only
>   manner. Loopy was developed as a plug-in for Apache Commons VFS.
>   Currently, it only supports the ISO9660 file system (i.e. .iso files).

Comment: Is there any other alternative which is actively being maintained? Seems these libraries are not being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The code to read the `ISO9660 CD filesystem` can be generated based on the language `Kaitai Struct`.

https://formats.kaitai.io/iso9660/java.html